# Disable Own Word 2007 Add-In If No Document Loaded

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, add-in, ribbon-control

I've developed an application-level add-in for Word 2007 using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 3.5. Part of what it does is use the

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range
```

to insert text.

However, when there is no document loaded this code fails. I could catch the exception or programmatically detect whether a document was currently open, but I think there must be an easier way...

When Word 2007 is open but no document is loaded, most of the buttons on the ribbon are disabled (that is, greyed out).

Any idea how this is achieved?
Will the add-ins hook into an event and disable their buttons accordingly?
If so, would this be the

```
DocumentBeforeClose
```

event, and could this be risky if Word is somehow opened without a document? (That is, there's no document loaded, but the event hasn't yet been triggered.)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
OK, it seems like making use of the

```
getEnabled="MyMethod"
```

attribute of the XML might be the way forward, but this seems to only work for the individual controls on the Ribbon rather than the whole ribbon itself.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered your own question.

> I could catch the exception or
>   programmatically detect whether a
>   document was currently open

Catching the exception is a bit nasty, but would work.

Programmatically detecting whether there is a document loaded is the best alternative.

And it's easy.

```
  If Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Count > 0 then
        'at least one document is opened
  end if
```

Can't get much easier than that.

Is there something else you were trying to accomplish with the stuff about the buttons on the ribbon?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The IF statement you provided would of course work, but if I was to have say, 20 buttons on my ribbon, I'd have to start every button's Click Event handler with the IF. However, if you launch Word itself and then close all open documents all the ribbons except 'Developer' and my own one are automatically greyed out. I was hoping to mimic this... my Ribbon either detects there are no more open docs and disables itself, or reacts to an event that tells it to disable itself..? Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DocumentChange event instead (see my answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399111/vsto-enable-ribbon-button-only-when-a-document-is-loaded/6649419#6649419)).