# Changing the VSTO tab's visible property through the Workbook_Open event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have written the Ribbon.xml file for an Excel VSTO project.  The tab element looks like this:

```
<tab id="myId" idMso="TabAddIns" label="My Tab" visible="false">
```

When a workbook is opened, I want the tab to be hidden by default, which is accomplished through the visible property being set to false.  Next, I want to change the visible property to true in the Workbook_Open event.  This is where I'm stuck.  I wouldn't think this would be hard, but I've spent a couple hours googling for the answer.  It seems that most examples 1) toggle a tab's visibility through a [button callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545350(v=office.12).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), which is not what I want to do, or 2) are able to access the [ribbon's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399111/vsto-enable-ribbon-button-only-when-a-document-is-loaded), which I have not been able to replicate so far (although, most of these resources are old, so I'm thinking that MS moved these properties around since then).

Does anyone know how to easily change the visible property to true so that the tab is displayed?

Thank you!

**UPDATED WITH ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

ThisAddIn.cs

```
namespace Doodles_Reporting
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public RibbonApi ribbonApi;


        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon();
        }

        void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
        {

            //first, check if there is an application/process for each workbook
            Excel.Workbooks books = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks;
            if (books.Count > 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    //close workbook that was just opened and then reopen it with new process/application.
                    string filePath = Wb.FullName;
                    Wb.Close();
                    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                    excelApp.DisplayFullScreen = true;
                    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //second, check if the workbook is a Doodles workbook
                try
                {
                    DocumentProperties props = (DocumentProperties)Wb.CustomDocumentProperties;
                    var selectedTable = props["selectedTable"].Value;
                    configureDoodles();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                 //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SET THE RIBBON VISIBILITY TO FALSE
                }
            }   
        }

        private void configureDoodles()
        {
            RibbonApi.app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            RibbonApi.wBookPropertiesConfig = new WorkbookPropertiesConfig(RibbonApi.app.ActiveWorkbook);
            RibbonApi.presenter = new ExcelPresenter(RibbonApi.app.ActiveWorkbook);
            ribbonApi = new RibbonApi();
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
            this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Ribbon.cs

```
namespace Doodles_Reporting
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Ribbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public Ribbon()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("Doodles_Reporting.Ribbon.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=271226

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        public bool toggleVisibility(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            return (control.Id == "TabAddIns") ? true : false;
        }

        public void onSomeEvent()
        {
            this.ribbon.InvalidateControl("TabAddIns");
        }

        public void SignIn(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonApi.signIn();
        }

        public void SqlCreatorFormLoad(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonApi.showSqlCreator();
        }

        public void refreshData(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonApi.refreshData();
        }

        public void drilldownSelectionLoad(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonApi.setDrilldownColumns();
        }

        public void Drilldown(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonApi.drilldown();
        }

        public void editProperties(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonUI)
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working?  Is it that you can't get a reference to the tab from the Workbook_Open handler (use a static field), or is it that that doesn't work?

Comment: Right, I can't get a reference to the tab from the Workbook_Open handler.  Forgive my ignorant question, but what should the static field be?   

I also came across this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx), but I'm not able to find my ribbon name under Globals.Ribbons.

Comment: Which fires first? `Application_WorkbookOpen` or `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`?

Comment: CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject

Comment: Posted another answer, but I realized the more important question is: Which fires first -- `Application_WorkbookOpen` or `Ribbon_Load`?

Comment: Ribbon_Load.  All events related to the ribbon fire before any workbook related events.

Answer (score 4):

The ribbon is a funny beast. It's specifically designed to disallow you to get direct access to any of its elements and to disallow you to directly manipulate them. Instead, everything is accomplished via callbacks. I don't have a lot of experience with VSTO, but I can explain what you would do in C# or C++ without VSTO, and I believe you can fill in the gaps.

1. Set an `onLoad` callback in your ribbon XML. Excel will call this method (via `IDispatch`) when the ribbon is first loaded.

   ```
   <customUI ... onLoad="OnRibbonLoaded">
   ```
2. Implement your `onLoad` callback, which should store the `IRibbonUI` reference that's provided.

   ```
   public void OnRibbonLoaded(IRibbonUI ribbon)
   {
       this.ribbon = ribbon;
   }
   ```
3. For the properties you want to dynamically control, define a callback in the ribbon XML.

   ```
   <tab ... getVisible="GetVisible">
   ```
4. Implement your visibility callback. If multiple parts of your ribbon use the same callback, the `IRibbonControl` instance passed in to this method can be used to determine which tab/group/control is being queried.

   ```
   public bool GetVisible(IRibbonControl control)
   {
       // here is where you should determine if your tab/group/control should be visible,
       return (some condition) ? true : false;
   }
   ```
5. Whenever you decide that you want to update the visibility, tell Excel to re-query your control's properties (i.e. call your callbacks) by using the `IRibbonUI` reference.

   ```
   void OnSomeEvent()
   {
       // you can tell Excel to update the entire ribbon
       this.ribbon.Invalidate();

       // or you can tell Excel to update a single tab/group/control
       this.ribbon.InvalidateControl("my_id");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  I understand the steps you laid out, but I think things become complicated because I'm essentially wanting the GetVisible method to be called in the Workbook_Open event.  The Workbook_Open event is in the ThisAddIn class, which is instantiated automatically by the VSTO runtime.  The ribbonUI is instantiated by an overridden method, CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject, but this method doesn't instantiate a field in the ThisAddIn class.  It seems to instantiate a ribbonUI variable somewhere internally.  So, I'm stuck because I can't reference the ribbon from the ThisAddIn class.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got all the pieces.

In `ThisAddin`, you're overriding `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`. Instead of returning a `new Ribbon`, return an object that you keep hold of.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private readonly Ribbon _ribbon = new Ribbon();

    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return this._ribbon;
    }
}
```

Then, either add a public `Invalidate()` method(s) to that object, or make that object's `IRibbonUI` field public and call `Invalidate`/`InvalidateControl` on that. I would probably do the former.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Ribbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI _ribbonUI;

    public void Invalidate()
    {
        this._ribbonUI.Invalidate();
    }

    public void InvalidatePlayButton()
    {
        this._ribbonUI.Invalidate("PlayButton");
    }
}
```

Then call those public methods from `Application_WorkbookOpen`.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
    {
        this._ribbon.Invalidate();
        this._ribbon.InvalidatePlayButton();
    }
}
```

Note that you can combine these objects into a single object, if you like. Just have `ThisAddin` implement `Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility` and return `this` from `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`.

However, there are some advantages to creating a separate object. For example, it becomes easy to encapsulate your ribbon in more robust public methods and properties. For example:

```
public class Ribbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI _ribbonUI;

    private bool _isPlayButtonVisible = true;

    // here's a property that makes it easy to update the visibility of the play button
    public bool IsPlayButtonVisible
    {
        get { return this._isPlayButtonVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (this._isPlayButtonVisible != value)
            {
                this._isPlayButtonVisible = value;
                this._ribbonUI.InvalidateControl("PlayButton");
            }
        }
    }

    // here's the callback that Excel will call
    public bool GetIsPlayButtonVisible(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return this.IsPlayButtonVisible
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael, but Invalidate doesn't hide the control, right?  It only empties the control's cache.  I think in order for this to work I would need to still have a GetVisible callback method which would update the _isPlayButtonVisible field.  Essentially the IsPlayButtonVisible method would become the GetVisible callback method, right?  And all it would do is !_isPlayButtonVisible.

Comment: Yes, you still need the callback. Unfortunately, you can't use properties as callbacks, so you need either a `GetVisible` or `GetPlayButtonVisible` method. I'll update the last code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how to do this with a ribbon from designer:

If you tried this:

```
Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyRibbonTab.Visible = false;
```

And nothing happened, try setting all your RibbonGroups to Visible = false.
When all RibbonGroups inside your Ribbon are Not visible, the whole ribbon will automaticly set to Visible = false.

```
private void SetRibbonVisibility(bool visible)
    {
        foreach (var ribbonGroup in Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon.MyRibbonTab.Groups)
        {
            ribbonGroup.Visible = visible;
        }
    }
```

Yes, VSTO is a joy to work with.

Comment: Note: I doesn't seem to work, if you set the tab visibility to false in the designer before.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that using the Ribbon Designer makes this far simpler.  After I create a new Ribbon Designer class, the class is added to the object model under `Globals.Ribbons`.  All that means that hiding the tab becomes as simple as I thought it should be with one line of code:

```
Globals.Ribbons.RibbonVisual.Doodles.Visible = false;
```

Where `RibbonVisual` is the name of the Ribbon Designer class I created and `Doodles` is the name of the tab.

I'll be using the Ribbon Designer from now on lol :P.