# Refresh the VSTO tab's getvisible state everytime I click the specific tab

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm developing a VSTO Excel-AddIn 2010 project.

I am trying to make a tab "isInstalled" be visible or not decided by check whether a specific program is installed on the computer. Therefore, I added the getVisible attribute in the tab and write a callback function to check and return true or false.

```
public bool IsInstalled(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if(isSoftwareinstalled(control.id)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

```
<button id="office" label="Launch"  getVisible="IsInstalled" onAction="Launch"/>
```

However, when testing, I found that the getVisible only update ones when I first click on the tab. It will never update again unless I restart the program. I wonder if there is a way to let the tab update its getVisible status every time I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right avenue. All values are cached by the Fluent UI. If you need to get your callback invoked anew, i.e. re-valuate cached values, you need to use the [Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidate) method:

```
XML

<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>

-----------------------------------------

VB

Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
  Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 

Sub myFunction() 
  MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

Also, you may consider using the [InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) method which invalidates the cached value for a single control on the Ribbon user interface.

```
XML

<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddInInitialize" …>

-----------------------------------------

VB

Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 

Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.InvalidateControl("control1") ' Invalidates the cache of a single control 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have heard the Invalidate method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789975/changing-the-vsto-tabs-visible-property-through-the-workbook-open-event?answertab=votes#tab-top. However, I still have questions that where can I put the InvalidateControl(control.id) so that it can ensure that every time I click on the specific button, it will automatically update the getVisible. In other words, in your answer, where can I call the myFunction() to make the InvalidateControl valid.

Comment: There's no event for tabs that is similar to 'onaction', you'll have to run it at some other time that makes sense.

Comment: In the `Click` event handler you may call the `InvalidateControl` method of the `IRibbonUI` interface. To get an instance of the interface you need to handle the `onLoad` event/callback.